# PHP echo all subfolder images

Tags: php, foreach, echo, subdirectory, scandir

I have a directory with subfolders containing images. I need to display all these on one page, and also their folder name, so something like this:

- `echo Subfolder name`

   `echo image, image, image`
- `echo Subfolder2 name` 

   `echo image2, image2 , image2`
- etc

I've tried using

```
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
```

but the problem is I have to exactly define the subfolder name in `$directory`, like "path/folder/subfolder/";

Is there any option like some "wildcard" that would check all subfolders and echo `foreach` subfolder name and its content?

Also, `opendir` and `scandir` can't be applied here due to server restrictions I can't control.

Comment: PHP Glob doesn't support ** wildcard. You have to write a recursive function that does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glob normally have a recursive wildcard, written like /**/, but PHP Glob function doesn't support it. So the only way is to write your own function. Here's a simple one that support recursive wildcard:

```
<?php
function recursiveGlob($pattern)
{
    $subPatterns = explode('/**/', $pattern);

    // Get sub dirs
    $dirs = glob(array_shift($subPatterns) . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    // Get files in the current dir
    $files = glob($pattern);

    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        $subDirList = recursiveGlob($dir . '/**/' . implode('/**/', $subPatterns));

        $files = array_merge($files, $subDirList);
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Use it like that `$files = recursiveGlob("mainDir/**/*.jpg");`